# Phonegap and AJAX bad performance

Tags: ajax, cordova

I'm loading data to my application using an async AJAX call. This call takes some time as the server is very slow. Loading the application on the desktop or a phone as a web site shows the expected behaviour: Page loaded - some delay - site update with loaded data. Executing the page using phonegap is showing the splash screen, than a black screen and after a very long time (the time for executing the ajax call) the normal screen. I assume there's any reason that Phonegap is waiting for the call to be finished before displaying the content. Can this be prevent/configured?

Code sample:

```
function connect(){
    var username = window.localStorage.getItem( 'username' );
    var password = window.localStorage.getItem( 'password' );
    if(username!=null&&password!=null){
    jQuery.ajax({
            async: true,
            type : "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url : loginURL,
            success : function(data) {

                token=data.token;


                connected=true;
                oSettingsTile.setInfo("Connected");
                oSettingsTile.setInfoState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success);

                var oFeedModel=new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

                jQuery.ajax({
                type : "GET",

                url : feedURL,
                dataType : "json",
                async: true,
                success : function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {


                  oFeedModel.setData(data); 
                  oFeedTile.setInfoState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
                  oFeedTile.setNumber(oFeedModel.getProperty("/list/length"));

                },
                error : function(err){
                  oFeedTile.setInfo("Error loading");
                  oFeedTile.setInfoState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
                }

                });

                var oGroupModel=new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                jQuery.ajax({
                type : "GET",
               url : groupURL,
                dataType : "json",
                async: true,
                success : function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  oGroupModel.setData(data); 
                  oGroupTile.setInfoState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
                  oGroupTile.setNumber(oGroupModel.getProperty("/list/length"));

                },
                error : function(err){
                  oGroupTile.setInfo("Error loading");
                  oGroupTile.setInfoState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
                }

                });

                feedView.setModel(oFeedModel);
                feedDetailView.setModel(oFeedModel);

                groupView.setModel(oGroupModel);
                groupDetailView.setModel(oGroupModel);


            },
            error : function(err,status,errT){
              token="";
              oGroupTile.setNumber(0);
              oFeedTile.setNumber(0);
              connected=false;
              oSettingsTile.setInfo("Error");     
              oSettingsTile.setInfo(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I commented the ajax loading part:
jQuery.ajax({
        
                type : "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                url : "...",
                success : function(data) {
                ....    
Now loading is within 1 sec. So it is the ajax call Phonegap is waiting for

Answer (score 0):

you may think, that page is being loaded while splashscreen is on, but its not. Whole html/css/js is loaded after splashscreen is gone, thus if you have slow server, it will last some time until you see the content.

Comment: Why does it depend on the server? All the content is stored locally and data is loaded asynchronously. Loading the same application in the web browser is fast. I think phonegap is waiting for any signal

Comment: Slow response is not always necessary due to cordova / phonegap neither javascript but more on the code and the available infraestructure. Are you using any special UI framework? Phonegap does not wait for any signals, you should only watch for the deviceready event. If you have a large amount of data I recommended using a lazy loading approach instead of getting the whole data to only show some bits. First be sure if the server response is stable and acceptable.

Comment: I notice that you have nested ajax requests, so that is also something to watch, I recommended isolating each call and instead of writing the   other ajax requests inside, use a callback and inside the callback put your request. Be aware as of the async nature it is not recommended to trigger several ajax calls at the same time or in parallel (you will not know when exactly each call ended its work and you consume your call compite for device internet bandwidth), I faced some problems because of that, so try calling each request after the other has ended using callbacks, give it a tru.